# How to delete blank lines from a txt file with c, in linux - whitout Bash

Tags: c

I tried creating a .c program that when it is run it takes a file and it prints only the lines on which there is something (a space, a letter, a number....etc) not the blank lines.

I need to run this on a virtual machine using ubuntu(it's running the newest version of ubuntu). So far I have only managed to print it's contents but not on lines like they are in the file.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    char *name = argv[1];

    FILE *f = fopen(name, "r");

    char x;

    while(fscanf(f, "%c" , &x) > 0)
    {
            printf("%c", x);
            if(x == '\n')
            {
                    printf("\n");
            }
    }
}
```

file contents:

```
           as
           d

           3
```

results:

```
           asd3
```

desired result:

```
           as
           d
           3
```

Comment: Rather than reading the file one character at a time, why not read it one line at a time?

Comment: I do have this on standby, it's just that I do not know how to implement the checking of the characters in it:

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
       int main ( void )
   {
      char filename[] = "file.txt";
  FILE *file = fopen ( filename, "r" );

  if (file != NULL) {
    char line [1000];
    while(fgets(line,sizeof line,file)!= NULL) /* read a line from a file */ {
      fprintf(stdout,"%s",line); //print the file contents on stdout.
    }

    fclose(file);
  }
  else {
    perror(filename); //print the error message on stderr.
    }

      return 0;
   }

Comment: Unix is case sensitive, and you are a good linux user. Please write "I" in uppercase. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have no error checking. That makes your program difficult to use.

Second, you output every character unconditionally and then output newlines an extra time. What you want to do is output every character once, unless it's a newline right after a newline (as that would create an empty line) in which case you don't want to output it.

Here's the code fixed up:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
    if (argc < 2)
    {
         fprintf (stderr, "An argument is required\n");
         return -1;
    }

    char *name = argv[1];

    FILE *f = fopen(name, "r");
    if (f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open file for reading\n");
        return -1;
    }

    char x, px = '\n';

    while(fscanf(f, "%c" , &x) > 0)
    {
            // don't output a newline after a newline
            if ((x != '\n') || (px != '\n'))
                printf("%c", x);

            // keep track of what character was before the next one
            px = x;
    }
}
```

It really would be much easier to just read each line in and then output the line if it's non-empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use fgets() function which gets the entire line including the new line character (\n), After you read the line, you can skip printing the line if the first character (line[0]) is newline character.

Here is the code segment that does it, You need to error checking for argc and file existence as done by @David Schwartz

```
    char line[200];
    while (fgets(line, 100, fp))
    {
        if (line[0] != '\n')
        printf(line);
    }
```

This should work.